# Passing muliple parameters in get method of web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, get

I have web api get method with following parameters

```
public DataSet Get([FromUri] EloQuaParameters paramss)
{


Hive9Common obj = new Hive9Common();
            obj.credentials = paramss.credentials;
            obj.fromDate = paramss.fromDate;
            obj.toDate = paramss.toDate;
            obj.fieldMap = paramss.fieldMap;
//Credential & fieldmap always remain null
}
```

EloquaParameters is class as below:

```
public class EloQuaParameters
        {
            public Dictionary<string, string> credentials { get; set; }
            public DateTime? fromDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime? toDate { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> fieldMap { get; set; }
        }
```

I am calling this method from my application as below:

```
HttpClient client;
            string url = "http://localhost:54371/api/values/Get?credentials=" + credentialDictionary + "&fromDate=" + fromDate + "&toDate=" + toDate + "&fieldMap=" + fieldmpa;
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            }
```

In webApi method fromdate & todate parameter is receive proper value but both dictionary parameter is always remain null. how I can able to get values of that dictionary parameters.?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You really can't.  A dictionary is not designed to be passed in a url.  Think about what would happen if you had a large number of items in the dictionary.

You should really use a POST for this method for several reasons:

First, it will provide a way to specify your parameters in a single object, which can have its advantages.  Second, sending the parameters in a POST places those parameters in the body of the request, which will allow them to be sent over HTTPS, which you should really use anyway because you are passing credentials.  These days, there is no reason to NOT use HTTPS for everything.

It would really be a trivial change to send the parameters as a POST.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I have used post method and everything is worked.